# wcf service port

Tags: wcf

I have two processes running on the same machine. Each process is hosting a WCF service to allow inter process communications asynchronously. As of now, I have assigned a fixed port 8731 and 9000 to the two wcf services. What if a customer machine has these ports taken up? How can i dynamically make the wcf client find the wcf service if I were to dynamically allocate an available port?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late on this post, but today we have better solution for this problem.
There is a configuration endpoint known as listenUriMode(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.listenurimode(v=vs.110).aspx), if we set this value to "Unique", it will bind hostname to port 0 which will ask OS to assign a free port.

Now client can know about the server port using WCF discovery(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/wcf-discovery-overview).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're creating services in code.  If you're afraid of the client not having those ports available, [you should configure your endpoints using app.config.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx) That way, if a client has an issue with a port, you can simply change their config file instead of recompiling your code.

Comment: Is there a way to do detect and change this automatically in code and the update the app.config with the available ports to use?

Comment: @subbu Sure. If you can read minds.WCF allows you to open any endpoint you want (as long as security on the box will let you).  I'm in a similar situation--how do I allow people to define an endpoint without requiring them to edit app.config.  I determined there was no way other other than convention-no compile time safety.  It stinks, but as long as I make it obvious via documentation and prevent the user from making a mistake at the earliest possible moment, I make the "pit of success" as big as I can.  In my case, when dealing with WF, I don't have a choice.  You might have more, depending.

Comment: You could try to assign various pre-configured ports (for example, 9000, 9015, 9033, 8000, 11221,...) and have the client try all of them with some sort of detection query you will define. For example, say the service tried 9000 and it was taken, so it tries 9015 and it's taken and then it tries 9033 and it's free so it listens on that port. The client, will send some sort of "Are you the service I need?" query to 9000. When there's no response, it'll try 9015 and continue until it gets a response at 9033.

Comment: A simpler method, however, might be just using a file to which the service would write the port it's listening on and have the client read that file.